# Clicar num botao e conseguir os valores da linha de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Estou a fazer um projeto em nodejs / javascript e estou a tentar obter os valores que se encontram na linha de uma tabela. Ao clicar no botao que esta nessa linha vai me buscar esses valores e ira envia-los para outro pagina .

Basicamente quero obter os valores da celula da tabela atraves de um botao

este é o codigo da tabela ( nao é em html esta ser feito no controller que é da estrutura MVC)

```
function catalogo() {
//debugging para ver se foi pedido com sucesso
console.log(' pedido get  entrou success');
//criação de uma tabela para demonstração dos resultados recebidos
var txt = "";
txt += "<div class='table-responsive'>";
txt += "<table id='tblLivrosCatalogo' class='table table-sm'>";
txt += "<thead color:white '>";
txt += "<tr> <th>#ID</th> <th>Titulo</th> <th>Autor</th> <th>Género</th><th>Ano De Lançamento</th><th>Proprietário</th><th>Disponibilidade</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
//percorrer a variável data e por cada row cria a linha da tabela com os dados presentes
for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    if (lista[i].disp_req == "Disponivel") {
        // console.log(i)
        //aqui os id's são os do mysql
        txt += "<tr><td id ='id_tr'>" + lista[i].id_livro + "</td><td>" + lista[i].titulo +
            "</td><td>" + lista[i].autor + "</td><td>" + lista[i].genero + "</td><td>" + lista[i].ano_lanc + "</td><td>" + lista[i].user_prop + 
            "</td><td>" + lista[i].disp_req + "</td><td>" + "<button id='btnn'>Requisitar</button>" + "</tr>"
    }
    else {
        //aqui os id's são os do mysql
        txt += "<tr><td  id ='id_tr'>" + lista[i].id_livro + "</td><td>" + lista[i].titulo +
            "</td><td>" + lista[i].autor + "</td><td>" + lista[i].genero + "</td><td>" + lista[i].ano_lanc + "</td><td>" + lista[i].user_prop + "</td><td>" + lista[i].disp_req + "</td></tr>"
    }
}
txt += "</tbody></table></div>";
//envia a tabela construida para a view e mostra o resultado (txt) no object com ID result
$("#tablecatalogo").html(txt);
}
```

esta tabela é gerada depois de eu fazer um registo de livro que vai parar a base de dados sql e depois é lida nesta tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

> *Basicamente quero obter os valores da celula da tabela atraves de um botao*

Podes criar um `onclick` no botão que tenha um JSON com os valores da linha. Um exemplo seria:

```
+ "<button onclick='requesitar(" + JSON.stringify(lista[i]) + ")'>Requisitar</button>" +
```

e depois usares esses dados na função:

```
function requesitar(json){
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(obj.autor);
}
```

**NOTA:**  tens muitas IDs repetidas, isso é HTML inválido. Só podes ter 1 ID único por página.